# A Javascript Library to validate Python Regex?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a react UI which contains a regex validator/tester to make sure users give us the correct regex. However, our backend is using python. i know python regex is different than javascript. Therefore, i was wondering is there a Javascript Library to validate Python Regex? (I know python has js-regex which can validate js regex) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I found this on npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pyre-to-regexp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pyre-to-regexp

You can provide it a Python compatible regular expression string, and it'll return a JavaScript `RegExp` instance. You can use it to validate strings.

Please note that this hasn't been updated in 3 years. Therefore, what I would recommend is that you convert the Python RegEx strings to JS compatible ones. You can use a [visualizer tool](https://regexper.com/) if it's too complex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But how i can auto convert it?